# Cannot find name 'HttpParamsOptions'. Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, request-headers

maybe somebody know why  Angular doesn't understand the the HttpParamsOptions, or maybe there are another way for adding a request a header and params.

```
`public getJobs(options: {page?: number, size?: number} = {}, database: string): Observable <IJobs[]> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Dataset-Id', database);
  const params: any = {
       page: options.page || 0,
       size: options.size || 10
     };
 const httpParams: HttpParamsOptions = { fromObject: params } as HttpParamsOptions;
 const headerwithParams = { params: new HttpParams(httpParams), headers: headers };
   return this.http.get<IJobs[]>('/api/jobs', headerwithParams);
}`
```

Answer (score 7):

The [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) say that the HttpParams constructor can take an HttpParamsOptions object as its only parameter.

But the Angular team forgot to create any documentation for this class.

There is a lot of missing documentation in Angular.

Answer (score -3):

If you are interested in passing the http params, use [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)

For the HttpClient get request there are multiple overloaded `get` methods. see this [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

For just passing the headers, see below.

```
const headers = {};
headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
this.httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(headers);
return this.http.get<IJobs[]>(url_here, {headers: this.httpHeaders })
```